# How to get Transformation object from a job in pentaho through java api?

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle

I have a job with one transformation. I want to get the TransMeta or Trans object from the job and modify the same before executing the job. I am executing the job(.kjb) file through java.
I have used the following code:

```
JobMeta jobMeta1 = new JobMeta(filename, repo);         
Job job = new Job(repo, jobMeta1);
job.setInteractive(true);
Map<JobEntryCopy,JobEntryTrans> transFromJob =  job.getActiveJobEntryTransformations();
job.start();
```

But the transFromJob is empty. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem. I want to add row listeners to transformations in a job.